# Not getting expected result from calling object method

Tags: java

I have two .java files, one being a 'blueprint', the other containing only the main method. The issue I'm having is, I want to print the letter that corresponds to the number being inputted. I have it working fine for one "student" object, but when creating another "student2" object, the letter 'F' is printed every time no matter what number the user inputs. Please look at the code below to better understand.

```
public class StudentRecord


public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public int studentID;
public int courseGradeOne;


//create a constructor with no args.
public StudentRecord()
{

}//end of constructor without args.

public StudentRecord(String firstName, String lastName, int studentID, int courseGradeOne)
{
    //initializing variables.
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.studentID = studentID;
    this.courseGradeOne = courseGradeOne;
}//end of constructor with args.



/*
Setters & Getters for all 'fields'.
*/


public void setFirstName(String firstName)
{
    firstName = firstName;

}//end of setter firstName.

public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}//end of getter firstName.

public void setLastName(String lastName)
{
    lastName = lastName;

}//end of setter lastName.

public String getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}//end of getter lastName.

public void setStudentID(int studentID)
{
    studentID = studentID;

}//end of setter studentID.

public int getStudentID()
{
    return studentID;
}//end of getStudentID.

public void setCourseGradeOne(int courseGradeOne)
{
    courseGradeOne = courseGradeOne;

}//end of setter courseGradeOne.

public int getCourseGradeOne()
{
    return courseGradeOne;
}//end of getter courseGradeOne.


/*
Decision statements to determine "letter grade".
*/

public char letterReturn()
{
    if(courseGradeOne >= 90)
        return 'A';
    else
        if(courseGradeOne >= 80)
            return 'B';
        else
            if(courseGradeOne >= 70)
                return 'C';
            else
                if(courseGradeOne >= 60)
                    return 'D';
                else
                    if(courseGradeOne >= 50)
                        return 'E';
                    else
                        return 'F';
}//end of letterReturn.
```

SECOND .java file

public class TestStudentRecord
{

```
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //creating student1 'object'.
    StudentRecord student1 = new StudentRecord("Bob", "Smith", 111111, 100);

    //print information about student1.
    System.out.println("First Name: " + student1.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last Name: " + student1.getLastName());
    System.out.println("Student Number: " + student1.getStudentID());
    System.out.println("Course Grade(letter): " + student1.letterReturn());

    //blank prints to improve readability.
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    //blank prints to improve readability.

    //creating student2 'object'.
    StudentRecord student2 = new StudentRecord();

    //ask information about student2.
    System.out.println("What is your first name?");
    String firstName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is your last name?");
    String lastName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is your student number?");
    int studentID = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is your grade in the course?");
    int courseGradeOne = input.nextInt();

    //print supplied information to user.
    System.out.println("First Name: " + firstName);
    System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastName);
    System.out.println("Student Number: " + studentID);
    System.out.println("Course Grade(letter): " + student2.letterReturn());
```

As you can see the very last line is what is tripping me up, it always prints 'F' no matter what the 2nd student enters. Maybe I'm posting too much unnecessary code, but hopefully you can understand that, rather than my lame skills at trying to explain what I'm doing. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You never store any of the entered values into the second student's record.

Comment: Also please post complete code, otherwise it's just more work for other people to try to help. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: You call `student2 = new StudentRecord();` and don't call any setter methods on `student2`, so why are you confused that `student2.courseGradeOne` has a value of 0 (**zero**) causing `student2.letterReturn()` to return an `'F'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of setters and getters for the student2 object.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the getter/setter methods would help in the case of student2

```
//creating student2 'object'.
StudentRecord student2 = new StudentRecord();

//ask information about student2.
System.out.println("What is your first name?");
String firstName = input.nextLine();
student2.setFirstName(firstName);

//print supplied information to user.
System.out.println("First Name: " + student2.getFirstName());
```

Do the same thing for the rest, and it should work out.